# how to use two slider with one jquery plugin, also same setInterval

Tags: setinterval, clearinterval

I have prepared a slider and I want to use it more than once in a page. Therefore I am trying to prepare a plugin. The first slider which I have prepared doesn't work while the second slider works. In my opinion, ClearInterval doesn't work on first slider. Could you help me please?

Thank you,

Comment: I have the same problem. :/